# Stretch div to bottom with dynamic header height

Tags: html, css

It sounds like a pretty easy task, but for me it appears challenging and I didn't found a solution for this particular problem.
**The Task:**
I have an Image at the top that fits the width of the screen and has a **variable** height, so that the aspect-ratio of the image doesn't change.
Below that header are two more divs that should take the rest of the available height between header and bottom of the screen.
I found a lot of solutions that solve a similar problem, but in this cases the height of the header was always fixed. 

**Code:**

```
   <style>
        html, body{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .view-mainMenu{
            background-color: white;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        /*---------- Head ----------*/
        .view-mainMenu #mainMenu-contiHead{
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .view-mainMenu #mainMenu-header{
            width: 100%;
        }
        /*---------- LeftSide ----------*/
        .mainMenu-leftSide{
            font-size: 1vw;
            position: absolute;
            width: 52.5%;
            /* too much because position is absolute, height 100% == ScreenHeight */
            height: 100%;
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-right: 12.5%;
            text-align: justify;
        }
        /*---------- RightSide ----------*/
        .mainMenu-rightSide{
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            width: 25%;
            /* this is just a value that nearly matches the desired height */
            height: 80%;
            background-color: #666666;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div class="view-mainMenu">
    <div id="mainMenu-ContiHead">
        <img id="mainMenu-header" src="res/img/WA_Start_neu.png">
    </div>
    <div class="mainMenu-leftSide"></div>
    <div class="mainMenu-rightSide"></div>
</div>
```

Solving the problem by JS is simple but I try to find a pure CSS solution to get my JS code rid of styling issues that I (should) get solved by CSS.
**edit:**
Like kisabelle noticed correctly, my explanation was poor, I tried to upload an image of the layout, but I am not allowed to. Maybe this helps a little bit to understand the scenario 
 
---------------------------------
*|-------------picture---------|* height depends on picture aspectRatio
*|--div1-||--------div2--------|* div1 and div2 should fill the height
*|-------||--------------------|* between the picture and the bottom of the screen
*|-------||--------------------|*
*|-------||--------------------|*
*|-------||--------------------|*
*|-------||--------------------|*
*|-------||--------------------|*
*|-------||--------------------|*
---------------------------------

Answer (score 1):

Giving the div `height: 100%` solves the issue given the markup provided.

```
    #divToStretch{
       width: 10%;
       height: 100%
    }
```

Comment: ok, I forget to copy a part of the code, the #divToStretch was always set to position: absolute, so that the height of 100% was the whole height of the screen.If I don't change the position(but in fact I have to) it works.

Comment: It still works when given `position: absolute` (but this is without `top` `left` `right` `bottom` values). I think that you may not be providing a complete enough code sample for us to properly replicate your scenario.

Comment: you are completely right! I tried to minimize my use case, but its too confusing, I updated the description and the code - sorry!

Comment: height:100% works only because of the overflow:hidden in body, I would like to exactly match the bottom of the screen